# Facebook authentication token on multiple devices

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-access-token

I am integrating the facebook SDK in my application for ios. When the user login via facebook I am getting the token, and using it to authenticate the user in my app. The token will also be used to get the user information and validate the user on the server.

My question is this:

If the user login using facebook with the same account but on another device.

1) A new token will be send for him?
2) if so, what happen to the old one? does it get expired?

I know I can test and see what happens but we are still in the planning phase and we can't afford to spend time on implementing tests. Searching on google about this issue didn't result in any clear answers. So I would appreciate if someone has info about it

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question in case someone is looking for it

1) A new token get sent

2) The old token still works